# How to get contents of hidden divs within an accordion block with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, accordion, screen-scraping, hidden

I am trying to scrape amenities information from the "Ballpark Directory" on the right side of this page http://seattle.mariners.mlb.com/ballparks/stadium_maps.jsp?c_id=sea

I have been searching around for hours trying to figure out how to access the divs that are hidden inside the "accordion" div, which contains all the information in that Directory drop-down.  I have written the following code in Python, but when I try to access the divs inside of the accordion, there is nothing there (which can be seen when I tried printing out my variable accordion and the output was a div with no content).

```
html = requests.get('http://seattle.mariners.mlb.com/ballparks/stadium_maps.jsp?c_id=sea').text

# Convert HTML to BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
accordion = soup.find(id = 'accordion')
#print accordion
divs = accordion.find_all('div')
#print divs
for div in divs:
    item = div.find('ul')
    for venue in item.find_all('li'):
        for i in venue.find_all('p'):
            clas = i.get('class')
            if clas == 'section':
                venuetype.append(i.get('data-type'))
                venuesubtype.append(i.get('data-subtype'))
                venuename.append(i.get('data-name'))
                section.append(i.get('data-section'))
```

I would really appreciate any help on this matter, as I can't seem to access the html within the accordion div.  Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that the JavaScript is filling the <div id="accordion"></div> and so you don't get any content with your GET request.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone this is a correct guess, check out the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This section is formed via a separate XHR call which returns a JSON response.

Start a new [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session), visit the main URL, then make a separate request to "sea_map.json" and get the response via [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json):

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers

    session.get('http://seattle.mariners.mlb.com/ballparks/stadium_maps.jsp?c_id=sea')
    response = session.get('http://seattle.mariners.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/mobile/ballpark/iphone/config/sea_map.json')

    print response.json()
```

FYI, this is a source JSON that is used to form the section. You need to figure out how do they parse the JSON and form the list you want to scrape. The logic is inside [stadiumMaps.js](http://seattle.mariners.mlb.com/components/ballparks/js/stadiumMaps.js) file.

---

Alternatively, you can automate a real browser with a help of [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and get the list in a much easier way. Example using [headless `PhantomJS` browser](http://phantomjs.org/):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> 
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get('http://seattle.mariners.mlb.com/ballparks/stadium_maps.jsp?c_id=sea')
>>> 
>>> for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#accordion h5 a'):
...     print link.text
... 
ATM
Food
Info
Merchandise
Restroom
Specialty
Tickets
```